# Code Coverage on a LINQ projection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage

I have the following lines of codes in my application and I'm not sure why but Code Coverage is telling me that it is not covered:

```
var filters = from f in request.Filters
              select new FilterDTO
              {
                   FilterName = f.name,
                   Value = f.value
              };

var filteredItems = repo.GetFilteredItems(filters);
```

It considers the following lines not covered:

```
select new FilterDTO
{
    FilterName = f.name,
    Value = f.value
};
```

The rest of it is 100% covered. My unit test is creating a non-empty collection for request.Filters so I know that it is doing the projection right, but the code is still considered not covered.

Does anyone have any insight into why it feels just the select portion of the query is considered not covered by code coverage?

Comment: Broken code coverage tools? Did you evaluate the IEnumerable (with ToList() or similar) in the test or just create it?

Comment: It's the default code coverage tool for Visual Studio 2010 ultimate. It's possible that it could be flawed in implementation I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio 2012 to see if it's any different?

Comment: Have you looked at using a another tool such as NCover, OpenCover, PartCover? These tools have an XML output that would tell you were the  "code points" are and where they instrument. All this information in the end comes from the PDB files so they can only go with what they are supplied with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of what the profiler can tell you about what is and what isn't executed is based on what the compiler tells it in the debug information.

```
select new FilterDTO
{
    FilterName = f.Name,
    Value = v.Value
}
```

..is a lambda and the compiler translates that into a method on a generated class.  Also, the initializer syntax is converted to something like

```
var x = new FilterDTO();
x.FilterName=f.Name;
x.Value = v.Value;
return x;
```

The debugger is notoriously bad at stepping through code like that, so, it could be that the compiler just is generating enough information about it for the profiler or the debugger.